# Properly refreshing database connection pool using FastAPI + Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Currently using sqlalchemy and fastapi for a production microservice hosted in AWS. The issue is that our production database secrets are refreshed every 30 days. Trying to automatically fetch the new secrets from secrets manager to reinitialize the database engine and session in the event of an error or OperationalError from sqlalchemy.
My question is where should this "reinitialization" occur?

utils/secret_mgr.py

```py
import json
import logging

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def get_secret(secret_id):
    session = boto3.client('secretsmanager', region_name='us-east-1')
    try:
        response = session.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_id)
    except ClientError as e:
        code = e.response['Error']['Code']
        logging.exception(f'error:get_secret error_code:{code}')
        raise e
    else:
        secret_str = response['SecretString']
        secret = json.loads(secret_str)
    return secret
```

utils/db.py

```py
import logging
import os

from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Session, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
from api.utils.scemgr import get_secret

engine = None
SECRET_NAME = os.environ.get('DB_SECRET_NAME')
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'


def get_database_uri():
    secret = get_secret(SECRET_NAME)
    return SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL.format(
        username=secret['username'],
        password=secret['password'],
        host=secret['host'],
        port=secret['port'],
        dbname=secret['dbname'],
    )


def get_engine():
    global engine
    if engine:
        return engine
    conn_str = get_database_uri()
    engine = create_engine(
        conn_str,
        echo=True,
        poolclass=QueuePool,
        pool_pre_ping=True,
        # pool_size=15,
        # max_overflow=5,
        echo_pool="debug"
    )
    return engine


engine = get_engine()


#
# class SessionManager:
#     def __init__(self):
#         self.db = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True, expire_on_commit=False)
#
#     def __enter__(self):
#         return self.db
#
#     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
#         self.db.close()


def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except Exception as exc:
            session.rollback()
            raise exc
        finally:
            session.close()


def init_db_sqlalchemy():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


def fetch(db: Session, query, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        stmt = text(query)
        result = db.execute(stmt, *args, **kwargs)
        db.commit()
        return result
    except (Exception, OperationalError) as err:
        logging.exception(f"error_code={err} function_name={fetch.__name__}")
    finally:
        db.close()
```

```py
import os
import time
from uuid import uuid4

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from api.routes.info import info, health
from api.utils.db import init_db_sqlalchemy, get_session, fetch

app = FastAPI(
)
app.include_router(info, prefix="/info")
app.include_router(health, prefix="/health")


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_logging_and_process_time(request: Request, call_next):
    start_time = time.time()
    request_id = str(uuid4().hex)
    response = await call_next(request)
    process_time = time.time() - start_time
    process_time = str(round(process_time * 1000))
    response.headers["X-Process-Time-MS"] = process_time
    log_msg = f"request_id={request_id} service=my-svc url={request.url} host={request.client.host} " \
              f"port={request.client.port} processing_time_ms={process_time} env={os.environ.get('APP_ENV')} " \
              f"version=v1 pid={os.getpid()} region={os.environ.get('REGION')} "
    logger.info(log_msg)
    return response

@app.on_event('startup')
def startup():
    init_db_sqlalchemy()

@app.get('/getDatabaseInfo')
def get_db_data_example(db: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    try:
        records = fetch(db, DATABASE_QUERY).all()
        return jsonable_encoder(records)
    except Exception as err:
        logger.exception(f"function_name=getDatabaseInfo error={err}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8050)
```

I currently initialize the database on startup. In the event of a database connection error, where should we reinitialize the database? i.e. pull the new credentials from utils/secret_mgr.py and recreate the database engine in utils/db.py.

Given the above information a few questions:

- Should engine be a global object if we need to reinit every 30 days?
- If get_session fails, a dependency injection to the get request, fails it will close the session and add it back to the connection pool. If we are using a connection pool and one of the connections become invalidated, it will in turn invalidate all connections in the pool. This is okay, should happen. Where should we recreate the database engine?

What is the proper way to do this given the constraints above?